SSI interface to an encoder

I'm trying to interface a rotary encoder (IFM RM8002) with an Arduino Nano. The encoder uses the SSI protocol with RS-422 signaling. It has a 2-meter cable, no big stretch for RS-422.
I have a TTL / RS-422 module (amazon.com/gp/B07BJJ6C88) to provide the necessary level translation. It's powered by +5, same as the encoder. From what I've gathered, this is a plain-Jane SSI interface encoder and a commodity level translator.
I'm sending the specified clock signal, at 500KHz, in the correct polarity, but the encoder does not respond (its data lines never change). I've tried rates from 125KHz to 1MHz with no joy.
The scoped clock signals on the Y/Z pins are ~2.7V p-p. The spec I found for RS-422 levels seems to say that would be OK.
I don't know if this is a clue, but the A/B data lines from the encoder are both idling at 0V. Since this is RS-422, should they be at two different levels when idle? The encoder is definitely powered.
Is there some secret SSI sauce here that I might be missing? I have a call in to IFM tech support but they don't guarantee a quick response.

please add a schematic diagram of the circuit

Kinda hard to say. Usually it's not done with a uart. It's only a physical rs422 layer. You need something that does ssi - a microcontroller or an fpga. Or a servo drive.

@jsotola - added diagram

@TQQQ - sorry, I don't get what you're saying. Does the diagram help?

maybe the encoder is being held in a reset state

@jimMack it looks like you are trying to use a UART to read the encoder. I don't have your particular datasheet, but from what I remember it's nothing like uart, much more like SPI. So at best you'll get junk. On the physical layer I don't see a termination

@TQQQ - I'm not using a UART, I'm using an arduino nano, with TTL <-> RS-422 translation through a packaged component (labeled RS-422 in the diagram). It's the recommended setup.

@jsotola - No, I've ensured that it isn't. But it looks even simpler. I'll answer this one myself.

@JimMack what peripheral do you use to generate clock and read data?

@TQQQ - As shown in the drawing, an Arduino Nano handles that.

Do you mean, there is an of-the-shelf software you use? I was sure you are developing software that read the encoder

@TQQQ - I have written software to read the encoder. It runs on the Nano. Not sure why we're continuing this, but I'm always willing to engage.

I am curious. On one hand you wrote the software, on other hand your response to a peripheral question was unexpected, that's all

It turns out that while the encoder was getting power, there was enough loss in the USB cable powering the Nano that the voltage was just below the minimum 4.5V needed. The nominal +5v was actually 4.3V. Once that was corrected, everything works as designed.
Sorry for the distraction
